# Not able to update contact name in emulator 2.1

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am tring to update name of existing contact in android 2.1 emulator with the following code but always getting "**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Emplty values**" Exception.

ContentValues contactValues = new ContentValues();
contactValues.put(People.NAME, "rishabh"); 
getContentResolver().update(UpdateContactUri, contactValues, null, null);

UpdateContactUri is the uri of existing contact with id 4.
It is working on emulator 1.6 but not on 2.1.

One more thing i need to ask how can i access indivisual fields of Name(first, middle, last) and Address(Street, city, state, zip, country) in 2.1

Answer (score 0):

in android 2.1, I use this hack code to update contact name:

```
public static void modifyPeopleName(ContentResolver cr, String id,
        String sName) {
    if (sName == null)
        return;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    int android_sdk_version = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);
    if (android_sdk_version < 7) {
        values.put(People.NAME, sName);
        cr.update(People.CONTENT_URI, values, People._ID+"="+id, null);
    } else {
        values.put("data1", sName);
        cr.update(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/"),
                values, "raw_contact_id=" + id, null);
    }
    return;
}
```